# Parameter passing methods

Tags: dynamic, language-agnostic, static, parameter-passing

I need to make some things clear before my exam. Can you help me to answer the following question? If Im mistaken I wan to fix it and learn the true answer.

Thank you!!!

```
int x = 1; 
int foo (int a) { return a + bar (x) + x; } 
int bar (int b) { b++; return b * x; } 
int main () { int x = 2; foo(x);  }
```

What is the output for the following cases:

**a) Static scope and pass by value.**

5 :: foo->2 * bar (x) + x-> 2 + [2 (b) * 1 (global x)] + 1 (global x)

**b) Static scope pass by reference.**

8 :: foo->2 * bar (x) + x-> 2 + [2 (b) * 2 (global x changed)] + 2 (global x changed)

**c) Static scope pass by value-result.**

8 :: foo->2 * bar (x) + x-> 2 + [2 (b) * 2 (global x changed)] + 2 (global x changed)

**d) Dynamic scope and pass by value.**

10 :: foo->2 * bar (x) + x-> 2 + [3 (b was x from main which is 2 and we add it 1) * 2 (foo x from main)] + 2 (foo x from main)

**e) Dynamic scope and pass by reference.**

15 :: foo->2 * bar (x) + x-> 2 + [3 (b was x from main which is 2 and we add it 1) * 3 (foo x from main and since it was aliased by b it increases too)] + 3 (foo x from main)

Comment: What do **you** think the output is in the various cases (with your argument for why you believe this)? To ask good questions on [so], you need to show some attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to add my answers. Thx for reminding.